# React Native list view does not render whole list

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native

I have this simple sample app, that tries to render 100 rows in listview.
What I want to achieve is to render them all once the view is mounted so that user can smoothly scroll whole list.
As you can see in example below, it renders upcoming rows only after swiping the list down which makes it quote slow.
I tried to set the "initialListSize" prop to the length of the data array but that doesn't seem to change anything.
Any ideas how to render whole list?

[Sample App](https://rnplay.org/apps/_KAyCw)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add the `ListView` props this:

```
removeClippedSubviews={false}
```

[This is the docs about this props you just added](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#removeclippedsubviews)

And also take a look at the prop `pageSize`, [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#pagesize)

Comment: Thanks.
pageSize along with the scrollRenderAheadDistance is the way to control how list view is rendering rows that are outside of the screen.

Comment: @karol.barkowski please mark this answer as solution. Thanks.

Comment: That did not work for me but this did: initialListSize={1000} on the ListView props. (just a large number so it will go through all the initially visible rows.  I had a grid view layout so maybe that is why the accepted answer didn't work for me.